# Compute spline curve that goes through an array of points in 3D space

Tags: 3d, space, points, curve, spline

Given a list of points in 3D space I would like to compute a spline curve (or something similar) that smoothly goes through all of those points in order.
Does anyone know of a an existing tool that can do this?

Thank you

Comment: 3D Max (Bezier curve tool) perfectly fits your question.

Answer (score 0):

[SISL](http://www.sintef.no/sisl) is a C library that can do what you are asking for.